# Enforce PHP coding conventions for continuous integration

Tags: php, continuous-integration

I guess, it's an off-topic question, but let me try to ask it. I've just started learing about [Continuous Integration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321336380) and now I know that for Java language there are tools like Checkstyle and PMD that enable to enforce coding standards and to report any lines of code that are not meeting these standards.

And now I wonder if there are similar tools for PHP language, that I could incorporate to my Continuous Integration system. What If want all my codes to follow [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) and [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) specification. Are there any tools for PHP that can automate this process - check the whole code base and find files which do not meet the requirements etc.?

Comment: If you are down voting, please, share what is wrong with that

Comment: _"I guess, it's an off-topic question"_ You nailed it in your first line.

Comment: But it was just a guess. I think it is off-topic, because there is no code in it, but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: Well, I described that I've started to learn Continuous Integration, and that for Java there are some specific tools that enable to implement an important part of Continuous Integration. Now I'm just asking if there is something similar for PHP. I doubt that such a question may attract opinionated answers and spam

Comment: It doesn't matter, we can't pick and choose between things that may or may not, your question is off-topic, end of. (Not to sound rude but there is little to discuss, it's just simply off-topic to ask for libs / tools / w.e)

Comment: The catch is Continuous Integration is all about tools. But I see what you mean

Comment: The issue simply lies with the fact that if we start to allow one set of "recommend X kind of tools" then suddenly we'll have a ton of people complaining that their "recommend X kind of tools" questions got closed and so on. That's why all of them have to be off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer).

For example, to verify code for PSR-2 compliance use `phpcs --standard=PSR2 src`.

Also, I recommend to check out [this PHP package boilerplate](https://github.com/hexlet-boilerplates/php-package). It has some basic CI setup with Travis CI and Codeclimate that might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you, sir! You are the best!